# connecting matlab to c language dll

Tags: c++, c, matlab, dll

i'm trying to use clllib function in matlab i put .dll file and .h file in the same directory as the .m MATLAB file being developed and after that i try to use loadlibrary function bui it have some warnings

warnings:

```
Warning: 
Message from C preprocessor:

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\MAHNAZ\Documents\MATLAB\T1Header.h:1 Could not find include file
<iostream>

lcc preprocessor warning: C:\Users\MAHNAZ\Documents\MATLAB\T1Header.h:21 EOF inside comment

> In loadlibrary at 351

Warning: The function 'Add' was not found in the library

> In loadlibrary at 435

Warning: The function 'Function' was not found in the library

> In loadlibrary at 435
```

when I want to use the `calllib` function like this: `calllib('t1', 'Add', 2,3)` matlab gives me an error:

```
??? Error using ==> calllib Method was not found.
```

my header file is:

```
#ifndef T1_HEADER_H
#define T1_HEADER_H
extern int Add( int a, int b );
extern void Function( void );
#endif
```

my source file is:

```
#include iostream
#include "T1Header.h"

  extern int Add( int a, int b )
   {
       return( a + b );
   }

  extern void Function( void ) 
  { 
     std::cout << "DLL Called!" << std::endl;
  }
```

I use visual c++ 2010 and Matlab 7.6.0(R2008a)

Any suggestions on what is wrong, what I could do to fix this error, or what else I could try to call this .dll from within MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Some notes and comments up front:

- The error loading iostream sounds a bit like the code was being processed as C instead of C++.
- The source file you pasted doesn't have angled brackets around the name `iostream`, but I guess they got lost when you wrote this post.
- The functions shouldn't be `extern` when you define them.
- The error message you pasted mentions a comment which isn't included in your paste.
- I'm a bit surprised that matlab even looks at the headers, I would have assumed it uses the DLL file only.

But the main reason for this problem, assuming that the DLL file got created eventually, should be this: Matlab probably will want to use **C calling conventions**, so you should enclose your functions in `extern "C" { … }` blocks both in the header and in the implementation.

Comment: i changed my header file and source file:

 extern "C"

 {
   int Add( int a, int b )

   {
      return( a + b );
   }

  void Function( void )
   {
      
    printf("DLL Called.\n");
   }

}

>> loadlibrary('t1.dll', 'T1Header.h')

Warning: Message from C preprocessor:
lcc preprocessor warning: C:\Users\MAHNAZ\Documents\MATLAB\T1Header.h:21 No newline at end of
file

> In loadlibrary at 351

Warning: The function 'Add' was not found in the library

> In loadlibrary at 435

Warning: The function 'Function' was not found in the library

 and calllib function don't find ADD method